# Interromper processo em caso de falha ou dados inválidos

Tags: elixir

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em elixir e tenho um determinado processo que executa 6 ações em cadeia. Minha dúvida é como poder interromper essa execução cada uma dessas 6 ações tenha um problema.

Eu não gostaria de cascatear em de vários blocos case.

Comparando com OO eu gostaria de um return.

Alguém tem uma boa solução pra isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No paradigma funcional, pelo conceito de purismo, você não usa [exceções para controle de fluxo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345665/6241184). É por isso que muitas funções retornam uma tupla `{:ok, _}` ou `{:error, _}`, ou simplesmente `:ok` e `:error`.

Para verificar o retorno de várias chamadas, evitando cadeias de `if`, usa-se a cláusula `with`. Um exemplo:

```
with {:ok, %{id: external_id}} <- Parser.parse_body(body),
     {:ok, tweet} <- TwitterApi.get(external_id),
     {:ok, message} <- Messaging.create_message(tweet) do
  respond_with_status(200)
else
  {:error, cause} -> respond_with_status(400)
  :error -> respond_with_status(502)
end
```